# Displaying JSON data

Tags: python, django

In django my  view.py is

```
import json      
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def ajax(request):
    obj =[dict(a = 1,b = 2)]
    jsons=json.dumps(obj)
    print jsons 
    return render_to_response("2.html", {"obj_as_json": jsons})
```

I want to display  value of a and b that are JSON in my template 2.html. Please help me to write the code.

Comment: You can pass `obj` to template and show them as `{{obj.a}}`

Answer (score 1):

**I don't understand the usage of View.**

Why do you want to pass JSON object as a context value while Template Rendering ?

The **standard** is When you do a Ajax request **its response should be a JSON response i.e mimetype=application/json**.

So, **You should render the template normally and Convert the result into JSON and return.**
e.g:

```
def ajax(request):
    obj = {
       'response': render_to_string("2.html", {"a": 1, "b": 2})
    }
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(obj), mimetype='application/json')
```

**OR**

you can create a JSONResponse class Similar to HttpResponse to make it generic . e.g.

```
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """
        JSON response
    """
    def __init__(self, content, mimetype='application/json', status=None, content_type=None):
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(
            content=json.dumps(content),
            mimetype=mimetype,
            status=status,
            content_type=content_type,
        )
```

and use like :  `return JSONResponse(obj)`

This has been added by default in django 1.7: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects